# integrate the following equation (what am I doing wrong here 2)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Here is the equation:

$$\int 3x \sqrt{1-2x^2}dt$$

Here is my answer:

$$  \dfrac14 \int (1-2x^2)^{1/2} . 3x = -\dfrac14 \dfrac{(1-2x^2)^{3/2}}{3/2} = -\dfrac14 \cdot \dfrac23 (1-2x^2)^{3/2} + c$$

correct answer:

it should be -1/2 instead of -1/4 . 2/3 at the end. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You missed a factor of 3. Try to derivative your result and see where's missing.

Comment: It should be $dx$, not $dt$.

Comment: It is not an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us denote $s=1-2*x^2$,then $ds=-4*xdx$ ,because  you have $3$ in your equation,outside of integrat  will come  $-3/4$,so it would be

$$\int (-3/4)*\sqrt{s}ds$$

can you continue from this?

Comment: so it would be 12x....

Comment: no look please  ,i have updated

Comment: you are welcome, good lucks

Comment: @CashVai any question ?if yes you are welcome

Comment: thank you very much! I will, stay tuned :DD

Comment: i am happy that my reputation is increasing :D

Answer (score 5):

let $$\sqrt{1-2x^2}=t$$ then $$-4xdx=dt$$ the integral becomes $$\int \frac{-3}{4}\sqrt{t}dt$$
$$= \frac{-3}{4}.\frac{2}{3}t^\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Denote $t^2 = 1-(\sqrt{2}x)^2$. Then you get $dx=-\frac{tdt}{\sqrt{2}x}$. So you get cancellations and the integral becomes
$$
-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \int |t|tdt= -\frac{t^3 \ sign (t)}{\sqrt{2}}+C
$$
or just $-\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{2}}+C$ assuming $t>0$.